# merge several images make android very slow

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code in java for android device, to merge some png images and create one bitmap and show in an Imageview. it works but after that the application will be too slow. what is the problem of my code? I think it is some thing like memory leak! is it right? and how to fix the code?

```
 public Drawable merge(Drawable a, String uri){
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = a;
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
        layers[1] = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);        
        return layerDrawable.mutate();

    }

 public void ShowImage(ArrayList<String> states) {

        img1.setImageDrawable(null);

        Drawable map = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emptymap);

        int i = 1;
        for (String state : states) {
            String layerName = state;

            String uri = "drawable/"+layerName;
            try {
                map = merge(map ,uri);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

        img1.setImageDrawable(map);
}
```

Comment: Hint: **never** go with empty catch blocks. Ignoring errors completely is a super-bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

LayerDrawable can be really slow for multiple high-res png drawables because it draws layers one by one in its draw() function:

```
 @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        final ChildDrawable[] array = mLayerState.mChildren;
        final int N = mLayerState.mNumChildren;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            final Drawable dr = array[i].mDrawable;
            if (dr != null) {
                dr.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be better to cache the emission of LayerDrawable into bitmap, and then use this bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(layeredDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
layeredDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
layeredDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, layeredDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), layeredDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bmp));
```

Another thing to check would be the png drawables size after loading them from resources. They might be too large if positioned in wrong resource folder (For example, 500x500 png located in drawable/ folder after loading for density = 3 screen would constitute to be 1500x1500).